# R: pglm package (sigma coefficient)

Tags: r, parameters, panel-data, mle

so I want to have a Poisson Regression with Gamma Random Effect, and I used pglm() package on my code,

```
library(pglm)
data(HealthIns)
la <- pglm(mdu ~ sex + disease + age, HealthIns,
          family = poisson, model = "random", index=c("id","year"), print.level = 0,
          method = 'nr', R = 5)
summary(la)
```

And the result is

```
Estimates:
             Estimate Std. error t value  Pr(> t)    
(Intercept) 0.4496831  0.0334185  13.456  < 2e-16 ***
sexfemale   0.1606985  0.0289382   5.553 2.81e-08 ***
disease     0.0401547  0.0022270  18.030  < 2e-16 ***
age         0.0010090  0.0007862   1.283    0.199    
sigma       0.9394810  0.0194958  48.189  < 2e-16 ***
```

What is sigma coefficient in here?
And is my code correct if I want to fit the data with this model ? Really need your help, thank you
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sigma is parameter of the Poisson model which will always return when you run such codes for pglm.